# Don't display the leading mantissa 1 in power of tens (with pgfplotstable)

Tags: pgfplotstable

In pgfplotstable, how can I display “1e-7” as “10⁻⁷” instead of “1⋅10⁻⁷” ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to print log-plotlabels as compact `$10^9$`.
Since PGF's `\datavisualization` command calls `\pgfmathprintnumber` with a float argument like `*.*e*` I simply replaced it with a trivial version fit for my plot:

```
\def\MyPrintNumber#1e#2x{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1 == 1 ? "10^{#2}" : "#1\times 10^{#2}"}%
    \ensuremath{\pgfmathresult}}
\renewcommand{\pgfmathprintnumber}[1]{\expandafter\MyPrintNumber#1x}
```

It uses plain-TeX to split off the mantissa, uses PGF's math function to check if it equals 1 (also catching 1.0 etc), and applies a fixed format.

Alternatively you can patch it to use siunitx's `\num` macro, which has an option that does what you want, but only if the mantissa was exactly `1` before rounding, i.e. it won't work for `1.0e9`, but does for `1e9`. So I'm detecting if the mantissa rounds to 1 using PGF, and then pass the exact 1:

```
\sisetup{retain-unity-mantissa=false}
\def\MyPrintNumber#1e#2x{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1 == 1 ? "\num{1e#2}" : "\num{#1e#2}"}%
  %                             ^ no # here!  
  \ensuremath{\pgfmathresult}}
\def\pgfmathprintnumber#1{\MyPrintNumber#1x}
```

In both cases:

```
before: \pgfmathprintnumber{1.0e9} = $1 \cdot 10^9$
after: \pgfmathprintnumber{1.0e9} = $10^9$
% and \pgfmathprintnumber{34} gives an error, but I can live with that.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to make my answer as short as your problem...

Go to `pgfmathfloat.code.tex` and found this:

> ```
> % #1: sign
> % #2: mantissa
> % #3: exponent
> % #4: CODE to display if the mantissa is drawn.
> %     This code will be shown just before the exponent. 
> %     Example: #4=\cdot
> % #5: CODE to display if the mantissa is NOT draw. (unused currently)
> %     Might be used to display '10^1' instead of '1*10^1'.
> % #6: CODE to display the exponent.
> \def\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl#1#2e#3\relax#4#5#6{%
>   \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/number format/@sci exponent mark}\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@e@mark
>   \ifcase#1\relax
>       \pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style{#2}#1#2e0\relax%
>       \expandafter\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}{#4#6}%
>   \or\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style{#2}#1#2e0\relax%
>       \expandafter\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}{#4#6}%
>   \or\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@style{-#2}#1#2e0\relax%
>       \expandafter\pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}{#4#6}%
>   \or
>       \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{\hbox{NaN}}{}%
>   \or
>       \ifpgfmathprintnumber@showpositive
>           \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{+\infty}{}%
>       \else
>           \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{\infty}{}%
>       \fi
>   \or
>       \pgfmathfloatrounddisplaystyle@shared@impl@@{-\infty}{}%
>   \fi
> }
> ```

Conclusion: either

- wait for update; or
- hack this macro.